# How to Remove a Class from a Sibling of a Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm working with the off-canvas script from Foundation and it isn't working out of the box (of course) when I try to use the submenu options. I realized it wasn't adding a class (move-right) to the ul's of the li's in the off-canvas navigation. So I wrote a script to add that class which can be found here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('ul.off-canvas-list li a').click(function() {
        jQuery('ul.off-canvas-list li ul.left-submenu').addClass('move-right');

    });
});
```

And here is how my HTML is structured:

```
<ul class="off-canvas-list">
    <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Name 1</a>
        <ul class="left-submenu">
            <li class="back"><a href="#">Back</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></li>
            <li><a href="#"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Name 2</a>
        <ul class="left-submenu">
            <li class="back"><a href="#">Back</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></li>
            <li><a href="#"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Name 3</a>
        <ul class="left-submenu">
            <li class="back"><a href="#">Back</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></li>
            <li><a href="#"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...etc
</ul>
```

My problem is that my script is adding the class to ALL ul.left-submenu's instead of just the one directly under the li that I click on. I can't figure out how to add the class 'move-right' to only the 'ul.left-submenu' child of the parents li that I clicked on and remove the 'move-right' class from the other 'ul.left-submenu'

I thought maybe using the sibling() selector, but I wasn't quite sure how to implement that into my script. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Another issue has arose and that is being able to close the opened "ul.left-submenu" by clicking on the "Back" which comes before the other li's in each ul.left-submenu. I updated the HTML above to include the "" and also have provided the script below that I tried using that hasn't worked.

```
jQuery('li.back').on('click', function() {
        console.log('close submenu');
        jQuery('ul.left-submenu').removeClass('move-right');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add it directly to the clicked element by using this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.left-submenu li a').click(function() {
        jQuery('.left-submenu').removeClass('move-right'); // remove class move-right from every elements with class left-submenu
        jQuery(this).parents('.left-submenu').addClass('move-right'); // add class move-right to the parent with class left-submenu of current element
    });
});
```

### Edit:

if in your updated code, you want to click only by `a` right after `.has-submenu`, you need this probably, so it didn't trigger `on click` for `a` inside `.left-submenu`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.has-submenu > a').click(function() {
        jQuery('.left-submenu').removeClass('move-right'); // remove class move-right from every elements with class left-submenu
        jQuery(this).children('.left-submenu').addClass('move-right'); // add class move-right to the children with class left-submenu of current element
    });
});
```

sorry for my mistakes not looking again for the code before posting it, because `ul.left-submenu` is in the same position with `a` and not it's children, you need to use `.siblings` to get `ul.left-submenu`, so change the code to this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.has-submenu > a').click(function() {
        jQuery('.left-submenu').removeClass('move-right');
        jQuery(this).siblings('.left-submenu').addClass('move-right');
    });
});
```

here's the working [Example in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/um95mshj/)

Comment: Check my updated code. I left out the a link that was the selector I mentioned in my script

Comment: I copied and pasted your code letter for letter and it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @user3532666, sorry my bad for not rechecking your structure before posting the code, updated the answer with a working example

Comment: I got what you're looking for. What you need is to target the next element in the DOM, using $(this).next().addClass('move-right');

Comment: I got it working yesterday from the code you posted the second time :) thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The target element is the grandparent of the clicked element so you can use the `closest` method:

```
$('ul.off-canvas-list li a').click(function() {
    $('.move-right').removeClass('move-right');
    $(this).closest('ul.left-submenu').addClass('move-right');
});
```

Comment: you have the best SO username ever

Comment: Check my updated code. I left out the a link that was the selector I mentioned in my script

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is too broad. If what you want to do is to add `move-right` to `left-submenu` when you click `has-submenu`, that's what you need to do:

```
    $('.has-submenu').click(function() {
        $(this).find($('.left-submenu')).addClass('move-right');
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x9zcav0p/

If you need to reset `move-right`, do this:

```
    $('.has-submenu').click(function() {
        $('.move-right').removeClass('move-right');
        $(this).find($('.left-submenu')).addClass('move-right');
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x9zcav0p/1/

---

Updated markup:
For your updated markup, you can target the next() element after the anchor tag:

```
$('.has-submenu > a').on('click', function() {
    $('.move-right').removeClass('move-right');
    $(this).next().addClass('move-right');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x9zcav0p/2/

Comment: Check my updated code. I left out the a link that was the selector I mentioned in my script

Comment: In this case you can use the selector $('.has-submenu > a')

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you want to add a class `move-right` to the `ul.left-submenu` that is directly under the `has-submenu` `li` that you clicked, right?

So:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Trigger the click only on the li's has-submenu
    $('li.has-submenu').on('click', function() {

        //Remove the class from other ul, if there's any
        $('ul.left-submenu').removeClass('move-right');

        //Finds the direct ul child using the '>' selector, and adds the class.
        $(this).find('> ul.left-submenu').addClass('move-right');
    });

});
```

Comment: I am using your solution but have run into the problem of closing out the ul.left-submenu that is active when I click on the first element found inside the active ul which is: 

    "li class="back"><a href="#">Back</a></li>

I need to be able to close out the active ul when you click on this li or the a inside of it. I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

jQuery('li.back').on('click', function() {
            jQuery('ul.left-submenu').removeClass('move-right');
        });

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your selector it targets all the ul.left-submenu elements you have, another way to target just the element clicked would be like this:

```
$('.off-canvas-list').on('click', 'ul.off-canvas-list li a', function (){
   $('.move-right').removeClass('move-right');
   $(event.target).closest('ul.left-submenu').addClass('move-right');

});
```

Comment: This isn't adding a class at all. Unless I copied and pasted it wrong, it doesn't seem to be working